# Why is "more complicated" typically not hyphenated as a compound modifier when before a noun?

Tags: hyphenation, modifiers, compound-adjectives

In the phrase "employees for more complicated work," shouldn't "more complicated" be hyphenated as it comes before the noun it describes?

After much searching online, I am yet to find a single case of somebody publishing the hyphenated "more-complicated" but this seems to disregard the convention regarding compound modifiers.

Thank you for any clarification.

Comment: More is not a noun that needs hyphenating to make things clear.

Comment: This is a **more complicated problem**: adverb adjective noun. Typical in English. No hyphen. A less expensive model, for example: same structure.It is not a compound modifier.....

Comment: No, because "more complicated" is not a compound word consisting of two bases, but a syntactic construction consisting of head+modifier. The bases of compound words can't normally be separated without changing the meaning or the syntax. Note also the possibility of inserting an adverb, as in "more intensely complicated".

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.  Could you please clarify why, for example, "lesser-known facts" should contain a hyphen?  I'm afraid I don't see the distinction between these two phrases.

Comment: One reason is that the bases in a compound word cannot be modified. We cannot have "lesser-well-known", but we can have "more intensely complicated".

Comment: Thank you @BillJ!